# Create document library same as existing document library

Tags: document-library

I want to create a document library same as existing document library. There is some setting 'save as template' but it's also copy all items or folder. I want only create document library with same structure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right there...Just uncheck/deselect **Include Contents** Checkbox while doing save as template.
[image]
 It seems that you have checked that option.

Comment: It will create same structure means same column & content type if we uncheck include contents